# Android: setOnBufferingUpdateListener is undefined for the type VideoView

Tags: java, android, buffer, android-videoview

My code:

```
VideoView mVideoView =  (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    mVideoView.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener(){
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

    }
});
```

But, the eclipse write this error:

> "The method setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new
>   MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener(){}) is undefined for the type
>   VideoView"

In turn I import the OnBufferingUpdateListener.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get that error is because ViewView does not contain the function setOnBufferingUpdateListener.

setOnBufferingUpdateListener is only available through the MediaPlayer class. Video View is a wrapper for both a surfaceView and a mediaplayer but it doesn't expose that function from MediaPlayer.

Comment: And I how use with the MediaPlayer class?

Comment: Using the Media Player class it much more difficult. Since video view is a wrapper it has been "dumbed down" for quick use. In order to use media player you will have to write your own View/Activity and implement those things. If you decide to go with the View route, i would suggest looking at the source code for VideoView and writing your own version, aswell as looking at Android tutorials with Audio and Video playbacks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I choose other way :D

Answer (score 15):

you can do like this:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                //do something
                }
            });
        }
    });
```